# My custom command in Forge 1.12.1 is not working

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I made a class that implements ICommand and registered it in my ServerStarting event. When I try to execute the command in Minecraft, I get a no permission error. Here's my ICommand implemented class:

```
List aliases;

public CMinecraftStoryMod() {
    aliases = new ArrayList();
    aliases.add("msm");
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "minecraftstorymod";
}

@Override
public String getUsage(ICommandSender sender) {
    if (sender.getEntityWorld().isRemote) {
        return "/minecraftstorymod";
    } else {
        return "/minecraftstorymod";
    }
}

@Override
public List<String> getAliases() {
    return aliases;
}

@Override
public void execute(MinecraftServer server, ICommandSender sender, String[] args) throws CommandException {
    if (!MinecraftStoryMod.gameInProgress) {
        MinecraftStoryMod.gameInProgress = true;

        if (sender.getEntityWorld().isRemote) {
            sender.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("[CMinecraftStoryMod] Attempting to start game in a multiplayer world..."));
            sender.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("[CMinecraftStoryMod] Checking out the number of players in this world..."));
            if (server.getPlayerList().getCurrentPlayerCount() > 0) {
                sender.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("[CMinecraftStoryMod] There are " + server.getPlayerList().getCurrentPlayerCount() + " players in the server! Generating fun..."));
                MinecraftStoryMod.gameHandler.startGame(server.getPlayerList());
            } else {
                sender.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("[CMinecraftStoryMod] The server has 0 players!"));
                MinecraftStoryMod.gameInProgress = false;
                return;
            }
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("[CMinecraftStoryMod] Singleplayer mode for this mod is still under construction. We're sowwy :)"));
            return;
        }
    } else {
        sender.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("[CMinecraftStoryMod] Another game is in progress! Wait for it ._."));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean checkPermission(MinecraftServer server, ICommandSender sender) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public List<String> getTabCompletions(MinecraftServer server, ICommandSender sender, String[] args, @Nullable BlockPos targetPos) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isUsernameIndex(String[] args, int index) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ICommand o) {
    return 0;
}
```

I know I registered my command properly because I can type /minecraftstorymod in game. I'm using Forge 1.12.1 14.22.0.2469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always returning `false` from the `checkPermission` method, meaning that nobody has permission to execute the command. You can always return `true` if you want anybody to be able to execute the command or return a different value depending on the sender.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the player is Op or has a permission node?

Comment: Use ICommandSender.canUseCommand with the permission level 4 for Ops and the command name. What permission system are you talking about? Neither Minecraft nor Forge have one built in.